# código no muestra nada por pantalla en Python

Tags: python

este es el código:

> ## Función para agregar un cliente a la lista
>
> ```
> def agregar_cliente(lista_clientes):
>     apellido = input("Ingrese el apellido del cliente: ")
>     nombres = input("Ingrese los nombres del cliente: ")
>     codigo = int(input("Ingrese el código de cliente (debe ser un número entero de 4 dígitos): "))
>     cliente = {'Apellido': apellido, 'Nombres': nombres, 'Codigo': codigo}
>     lista_clientes.append(cliente)
>     print("Cliente agregado con éxito.\n")
>
> # Función para eliminar un cliente de la lista por su posición
> def eliminar_cliente(lista_clientes):
>     posicion = int(input("Ingrese la posición del cliente que desea eliminar (debe ser un 
>     número entero mayor o igual que cero): "))
>     if posicion < 0 or posicion >= len(lista_clientes):
>         print("La posición ingresada es inválida.")
>     else:
>         cliente_eliminado = lista_clientes.pop(posicion)
>         print("El cliente", cliente_eliminado['Apellido'], cliente_eliminado['Nombres'], "ha sido eliminado de la lista.\n")
>
> # Función para modificar los datos de un cliente por su posición
> def modificar_cliente(lista_clientes):
>     posicion = int(input("Ingrese la posición del cliente que desea modificar (debe ser un 
>     número entero mayor o igual que cero): "))
>     if posicion < 0 or posicion >= len(lista_clientes):
>          print("La posición ingresada es inválida.")
>     else:
>         cliente = lista_clientes[posicion]
>         print("Ingrese los nuevos datos para el cliente en la posición", posicion)
>         apellido = input("Apellido (" + cliente['Apellido'] + "): ")
>         nombres = input("Nombres (" + cliente['Nombres'] + "): ")
>         codigo = int(input("Código (" + str(cliente['Codigo']) + "): "))
>         cliente_modificado = {'Apellido': apellido, 'Nombres': nombres, 'Codigo': codigo}
>         lista_clientes[posicion] = cliente_modificado
>         print("El cliente en la posición", posicion, "ha sido modificado.\n")
>
> # Función para mostrar todos los clientes de la lista
> def mostrar_clientes(lista_clientes):
>     print("Lista de clientes:")
>     for i, cliente in enumerate(lista_clientes):
>         print(i, "-", cliente['Apellido'], cliente['Nombres'], "(Código:", cliente['Codigo'], ")")
>     print()
> ```

```
# Función principal del programa
def main():
    lista_clientes = []
    opcion = ''
    while opcion != '4':
        print("Seleccione una opción:")
        print("1 - Agregar un cliente")
        print("2 - Eliminar un cliente")
        print("3 - Modificar un cliente")
        print("4 - Salir del programa")
        opcion = input("Ingrese el número de la opción deseada: ")
        if opcion == '1':
            agregar_cliente(lista_clientes)
        elif opcion == '2':
            eliminar_cliente(lista_clientes)
        elif opcion == '3':
            modificar_cliente(lista_clientes)
        elif opcion == '4':
            print("Gracias por utilizar el programa.")
        else:
            print("Opción inválida. Intente de nuevo.")
```

al ejecutar este código en la terminal no me sale nada no se estarían ejecutando los input o no se cual es el error, quisiera ayuda para darme cuenta de donde esta el error.
primero me tendría que mostrar el menú con las opciones y luego permitirme elegir, pero al ejecutarlo no me sale nada queda la terminal en blanco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asumiendo que estés ejecutando la función `main()` de alguna manera, el problema que tienes es que `opcion` es igual a `''` cuando tu programa llega a la condición `opcion != '4'` del `while`. Por lo tanto, tu programa nunca entra en el ciclo.

Lo más normal en estos casos es tener un ciclo infinito y una condición de parada que rompa el ciclo. Es decir, algo así:

```py
while True:
    ...
    if something_happens:
        break
```

En tu caso particular, podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```py
while True:
    print("Seleccione una opción:")
    print("1 - Agregar un cliente")
    print("2 - Eliminar un cliente")
    print("3 - Modificar un cliente")
    print("4 - Salir del programa")
    opcion = input("Ingrese el número de la opción deseada: ")
    if opcion == '1':
        agregar_cliente(lista_clientes)
    elif opcion == '2':
        eliminar_cliente(lista_clientes)
    elif opcion == '3':
        modificar_cliente(lista_clientes)
    elif opcion == '4':
        print("Gracias por utilizar el programa.")
        break    # <--- acá rompes el ciclo infinito
    else:
        print("Opción inválida. Intente de nuevo.")
```